# Looking for PC side scrolling game from around 2008

Tags: story-identification, video-games

As stated above. It was a side scroller set in a sci fi world. I remember it being on a space station thing. Had swords i think and im pretty sure it was turn based. Also might have had multiplayer. For some reason the words mecha or star keep popping in

Comment: Turn based side-scroller?  While certainly possible (there's games for everything), it's not likely. Are you sure of the terms you're using?

Comment: Description kinda reminds me of Blizzard's "Vikings" game, though only one of them had a sword, and it wasn't on PC, and it was released ages ago (though the GBA re-release was in 2003)

Comment: Perhaps a better fit at Gaming.SE, but I don't see how this has a VTC for "off-topic"

Comment: @tobiasvl They don't take Id requests without an "artifact"  - a sound or a picture - from the game. We had game IDs here before, but this one could really use more details.

Comment: "Had swords"..... Are you sure it's not just a "Sword of the Stars" game? If not, I imagine it's most likely a 2D Sci-Fi RPG with Turn-Based combat. "Side-Scroller" definitely isn't the right term to use.

Comment: Or, if it's not actually 2D, could it be one of the "Star Ocean" games? Those generally involve swords in space, though the combat isn't turn-based. That's more Final Fantasy's thing.

Comment: Or, a "Super Robot Wars" game, which involve tactical turn-based gameplay, usually from a 2D top-down perspective, where you command a bunch o' big ol' mechas, some of which wield swords and other melee weapons, even though you'd think chainguns and missiles would be more effective. Later ones could even have had multiplayer, because they were released on Game Boy Advance and you could break out the link cable.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo - you are falling down a bottomless pit from which there is no escape...

Comment: I think my last 3 posts there are probably a prime example of why you should include as much detail as you possibly can and try to do a good amount of research before posting a question like this here.

Comment: @Radhil Haha, I know, I'm done. I think those are the top 3 best contenders with the information we've been given so far, so unless OP comes back and edits their question, I'm not gonna say any more.

Comment: Do you remember what any of the characters looked like? Did you play as a party? How big was it? What did the swords look like? What did the enemies look like?

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty eclectic mix, and the closest thing I can think of is *Star Ocean*. I've only played part of the first game, but @DisturbedNeo mentioning it in a comment while I was typing made me more confident about this guess.

- The battles are from a side-on perspective (which might be what you mean by "side-scrolling"), though I think they're more real-time than turn-based. Also, the overworld locations are divided into "screens", some of which are side-scrolling.
- It's definitely sci-fi, and while I don't remember whether there's a space *station*, there's definitely a space*ship*.
- It starts off on a typical medieval fantasy planet (complete with swords) until three of the protagonists are beamed up into space by the aforementioned spaceship.

The bits that don't fit are that I don't think it had multiplayer, and I don't think it was ever released on PC (it was originally PS1, I think, then ported to PSP as *Star Ocean: First Departure*, which is where I first played it). It may have been, though.

Comment: Have you got any screencaps and links? Those could be helpful.

Comment: I don't have any currently, but I'll add some in when I get the chance.